# scatter plot in R of many data 10 or more

Tags: r

hello I must do a multivariate analysis to this data

[image]

but I have to make a scatter plot of the data and I don't know that very well

[image]

This with the pairs function, if there is any way to do it and make it presentable, thank you very much.

Comment: Try making your plotting window much larger, or plotting to a PDF with really large dimensions. Or making your dots really small with `pch=`.

Comment: I don't think you'll get much in the way of demonstrated solutions: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might give `GGally::ggpairs` a try. It's relatively automatic:

```
library(GGally)
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol = 10))
data[,2] <- sample(1:6, 1000, replace = TRUE)  
data[,3] <- rpois(1000,1)
data[,9] <- as.factor(sample(1:3, 1000, replace = TRUE))
ggpairs(data)
```

[image]